# Create a Slider and Custom ActivityIndicator for Streaming Audio

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, uiactivityindicatorview

[image]

I am Working with streaming `URL` and I need to create a `UISlider`(*control volume*) and an indicator(buffering/loading) like one in the above image.
Code I am using is

```
 _theAudio=[[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:streamURL];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
    [_theAudio play];
```

Answer (score 0):

refer this [Link](http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2010/06/10/iphone-add-an-uislider-for-avaudioplayer/)

or

```
 - (void)updateSlider {
// Updates the slider about the music time
slider.value = player.currentTime;
}

- (IBAction)sliderChanged : (UISlider *)sender {
// Fast skips the music when user scrolls the UISlider
[player stop];
[player setCurrentTime:slider.value];
[player prepareToPlay];
[player play];
}
```

// Stops the timer when the music is finished

```
- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying : (AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully : (BOOL)flag {
// Music completed
if (flag) {
[sliderTimer invalidate];
}
}
```

**for volume control** u can add below line in
sliderValue_changed delegate

```
[audioPlayer setVolume:slider.value];
```

but first set min slider value to 0 and max to 1.

Comment: I need a slider to increase/decrease volume . I am not getting you.